# Linear response theory, but with measurement issue

Tags: measurements, many-body, open-quantum-systems

In the standard linear response theory, the variation of an observable $A$ at time $t$ due to the perturbing Hamiltonian $H'$ is
$$\langle \delta A(t) \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^t dt' \langle [A(t), H'(t')] \rangle,$$
where all operators are in the interaction picture. In the derivation, we only consider the **unitary** dynamics due to perturbation.

However, in actual experiment, one need to **measure** the observable $A$, and we know that measurement gives **non-unitary dynamics** by the axiom of quantum mechanics. For example, if $A$ is the current operator $I$, then typically the current is **continuously**(!) measured by a detector.

I have several questions:

1. How to incorporate this non-unitary dynamics by measurement in the linear response theory? Is there any related formalism?
2. Since the linear response theory formalism without considering measurement is so widely used, I expect that in many cases one may **ignore the measurement issue**. When we can ignore the measurement issue? Maybe for arbitrary weak measurement, or measuring macroscopic object...?