# Linear response theory, project ideas

Tags: statistical-mechanics, education

As a part of a second course in statistical mechanics I have to present a project related to the subject of linear response theory. We have not talked about linear response theory in the course, so I have to study the subject on my own. I need to present the subject with as little mathematical rigor as possible and preferably give examples for ubiquitous systems that display linear response. So far it seems that the subject is very theoretical and I have not managed to find many examples. I would love to hear ideas about interesting cases where linear response manifests

Comment: This kind of linear response theory? A REVIEW OF LINEAR RESPONSE THEORY FOR GENERAL DIFFERENTIABLE DYNAMICAL SYSTEMS, David Ruelle https://www.ihes.fr/~ruelle/PUBLICATIONS/151response.pdf  ...or this kind of quantum mechanical methods? http://eduardo.physics.illinois.edu/phys582/LRT.pdf (see also, for QM linear response theory, http://home.uchicago.edu/~tokmakoff/TDQMS/Notes/8._Linear_Response_2-09.pdf)

Comment: see also this question and links therein: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/678770/226902